# Java getBytes does not return the same in test than in injectMock

Tags: java, arrays, mockito

I am trying to compare the result of this function:

```java
public  Map<String, Object> addToMap(List<String> keys, Map<String, Object> data) {
    Map<String, byte[]> map = new HashMap();
    emptyIfNull(keys).forEach(key -> {
      if (data.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, data.get(key).toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      } 
    });
    return map;
  }
```

with this:

```java
@Test
public void testAddToMap(){
    byte[] data = "data".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Map<String, byte[]> map = Map.of("label", data);
    List<String> keys = list("label","key");
   assertThat(mapping.addToMap(keys, map)).isEqualTo(map);
}
```

But Mockito says that they are not the same bytes.
The first one returns : `[B@75bdf892}`
while the second one returns: `[B@597d8aad}`
How come so?

Comment: Not sure what `mapping.getMap("label")` returns because I cannot see the declartion of `mapping`. But probably your test should be `assertThat(mapping.getMap("label")).isEqualTo(data);`

Comment: You seem to compare apples to oranges. First of all it's not clear what exactly you compare to what, as the first block of code is just a method, and the second block of code is group of expressions not even using the method from the first block. So what is the "first one returns" and "second one returns" in this context? What you call with what parameters to get those values?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to put the whole code here, so I just put the snapshots that interested me and were problematical. I had te rewrite a whole new test method that's why it was inconsistent. I modified it so it will be more clearer. I hope I didn't forget anything this time! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `addToMap` doesn't copy the values from the input map into the output map - it processes them (`data.get(key).toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`).

Your unit test has to account for that:

```
@Test
public void testAddToMap() {
    String testString = "data";
    byte[] resultData = testString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    Map<String, Object> inputMap = Map.of("label", testString);
    Map<String, byte[]> outputMap = Map.of("label", resultData);
    List<String> keys = list("label","key");

    assertThat(mapping.addToMap(keys, inputMap)).isEqualTo(outputMap);
}
```

---

The problem is that in `addToMap()` you do `data.get(key).toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

In your test method you have

```
byte[] testData = "data".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Map<String, byte[]> map = Map.of("label", testData);
```

In `addToMap()` you have

```
data.get(key).toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

which is (if we insert `testData` for `data.get(key)`)

```
testData.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

But `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` and `byte[].toString()` are **not** inverse operations!

For almost all Strings `str`

```
str.equals(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString())
```

will return false (except for some rare cases where `str` starts with "[B@" and happens to be followed by some hex characters so that `str` forms a string like "[B@597d8aad"

Answer (score 1):

Working example without casts:

```
` private static Map<String, byte[]> addToMap(List<String> keys, Map<String, byte[]> data) {
    Map<String, byte[]> map = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
    keys.forEach(key -> {
      if (data.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, data.get(key));
      } 
    });
    return map;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] data = "data".getBytes();
    Map<String, byte[]> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("label", data);

    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    keys.add("label");
    Map<String, ?> result = addToMap(keys, map);

    System.out.println(result.get("label") == map.get("label"));        
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for you replay.  If I follow you, I should just replace the toString().getBytes() stuff by a byte cast? Did I get this right? Because I tried to do so, but I got an error: `class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')` got an idea from were it comes?

Comment: Difficult to say where the cast error comes from, without knowing the whole code. I edited my answer, to work without the cast.